# Period Slot System Design

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have designed a system that is used in a School to manage Students being sent to a seclusion room. The Students are currently added to the system, and based on the period that they are added, calculates that they spend a full day in the room. For example if a student is sent in Period 3 on 02/03/2016 they would come out Period 3 on 03/03/2016. I am currently doing this by assigning each period a numeric value, and then calculating how long they should be in there for. For each period that they are in there, their behaviour is rated (Red, Amber, Green), so I have a periods table that has the following fields: ID, Seclusion_ID, P1, P2, P3 etc.

The problem that I now have is that staff are now wanting to change the periods from the default that the system calculates, and whilst it works sometimes, it is very buggy because of the numeric values.

Basically the was I see it is as a time slot booking system, but with another dimension, where data needs to be kept for each time slot.

Any help on the structure of the tables would be much appreciated, because no matter how hard I think about it, I just cant seem to get my head around it!?

Matt

Comment: Please show what you have so far. Read about SO MCVEs.

Answer (score 0):

Separate columns for multiple periods/slots is an anit-pattern. Have a table with a column for period number or id.

```
-- student STUDENT_ID on seclusion SECLUSION_ID spent day DAY period PERIOD_NO at rating RATING
Seclusion(student_id, seclusion_id, day, period__no, rating)
-- period PERIOD_NO starts at START_TIME and ...
Period(period_no, start_time, ...
```

(Maybe you are thinking that periods span slots; then there might be a `Slot` table like with the above `Period` table. Then a `Period` table might have `start_slot` & `end_slot`. Or if periods consist of non-adjacent slots then you might have Period with columns `period_no` & `slot_no`.)